# Fixing a broken NTVDM

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, 16-bit, ntvdm

## <sub>Problem:</sub>

About a week ago, the NTVDM on an XP installation broke.

## <sub>Symptoms:</sub>

The first symptom was that a 16-bit executable that is run during an auto-run batch file would hang and peg the CPU at 100% until `ntvdm.exe` is killed, at which point the batch file continues running (albeit without the work that the executable was supposed to have done). The next symptom was that a different 16-bit executable that is run as part of a shutdown batch script would hang, causing the script to fail.

Interestingly, they do *sometimes* work (~30%). In other words, if a program is run (from the *Run* dialog) 10 times, it might run correctly about 2-4 times and hang the rest of the time. This is mostly just with simpler programs that print something out or such as opposed to more complicated ones with UIs like `edit.com` or `command.com` which seem to *always* hang. A few select programs that are exceedingly simple (e.g., `crlf.com`: 578 bytes, `ret.com`: 1 byte, etc.) *always* seem to run and return without problem.

## <sub>Tests:</sub>

Some tests show that the problem is with the NTVDM itself and not just the specific executables (which worked just fine until recently anyway). For example, running `edit.com` opens a console and displays the editor, but is unresponsive to the keyboard and must be killed. In fact, even running `command.com` won’t work; it opens a console and shows the prompt then just sits there, unresponsive.

I checked all the related NTVDM files (and numerous other OS files) and they are all correct. I also checked several related registry entires and they all check out as well. The programs run fine on other XP installations (which is not a surprise since `command.com` and `edit.com` work as well); so it is that specific machine. The environment has not changed since the NTVDM stopped working, but I checked it anyway and there is nothing overtly problematic; `temp` and `tmp` point to existing directories with no LFN names, no broken variables with nulls or such, and while the `path` is long, it has been such for some time.

Files verified: `ntd*, ntv*, dos*, redir.exe, Mscdexnt.exe, *.sys`

Registry entires verified: `*\Software\Microsoft\Command processor, *ControlSet*\Control\WoW`, `*\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WOW*`

**The NTVDM and 16-bit apps work just fine in safe-mode on the machine in question; it is only in normal mode that they hang.**

## <sub>Question:</sub>

Can anybody think of anything that could break the NTVDM in a manner that produces these symptoms?

(To be clear; it is NOT the common error *“The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.”* Also, please don’t suggest using Dosbox or other VM software because that is not applicable, and moreover, the programs in question worked before, not to mention that Windows’ own 16-bit programs won’t work.)

Comment: What if you procmon running command.com on the good system and bad system and compare?

Comment: Actually, I had already tried that with the bad system itself to see if there were any file or registry references to non-existing or corrupt items. I found nothing of particular use that way. A comparison sounds good though. ↑

Comment: Could you disable all drivers apart from the minimal set loaded in Safe Mode, and then reenable them all one by one? (Faster way would be to binary search it - enable half, test, if it works enable half the remainder, if not then disable half of those you just enabled.)

Comment: The Safe Mode list is located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal`, and you can [disable drivers](http://mikemstech.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/how-to-disable-and-enable-windows.html) by going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and changing the `Start` values to `0`. This will probably be quite a tedious process, and you might want to consider scripting it if you are able to.

Comment: @Bob, well I don’t think any drivers or services had changed between the time it was working and when it stopped, but since it *does* work in safe-mode, it is certainly worth doing some tests (in fact, any old, standard entries can probably be skipped). I’ll give it a shot this weekend when I’m on the XP system.